# How to take attendance without my part and without disturbing the class

Tags: organization

I am working as a TA for a large class (approx 200 students). TAs generally use the following methods to take attendance along with them I listed corresponding issues:

1) Circulating the attendance sheet among students to mark their attendance

**Proxy attendance and my involvement ( need to verify again whether proxy or not)**

2) Shouting roll numbers after the completion of class and marking their attendance

**Disturbance and chaos in class and my involvement and late for students to attend immediate next class**

3) Standing at door and asking roll number of each student going outside and marking their attendance

**Chaos in class, late for students to attend immediate next class and my involvement**

I want a hack that is similar to 1st method i.e., without my involvement and should have no proxy attendance and allows students to attend for next class without being late.

Answer (score 11):

1) Quick verification for method one is to know the count of your students or maybe count how many chairs have remained empty. And check if the numbers fit with what you have in your attendance sheet.

2) If you know the numbers of missing students, you can ask who are the four missing students? This could be done much quickly then checking all the present one.

Answer (score 4):

Break the roster into a few lists that each fit on one sheet. Sort the student numbers or names or whatever, so people can easily tell what sheet they are on. Lay these sheets out and let the arriving students come to the sheets. So you're splitting the stream of incoming people into multiple queues.

You stand facing them as they approach the sheets so you only have to watch 4 (or 5 or whatever) students marking themselves (a checkmark?) as present.

This cuts a huge swath of "marking my friend present" cheating because the friend would have to be on the same sheet for this to even be possible. No one will get back in another queue to mark their friend... you'll see that. So all you have to spot is the rare instance where one student tries to make two marks on the same sheet.

Comment: Very clever... I like the multiple sheets idea!

Answer (score 4):

I make a set of labels or Cards and put them on a table at the entrance.   I tell them to take the card with their name and put it in the box on the table.  I then take them out of the box and post my attendance sheet  and save the cards for the next session.